# Cloudflare - Terraform - Enable SSL full encryption

Tags: ssl, terraform, cloudflare

I want to enable SSL full strict encryption on the whole Cloudflare zone.

From the Cloudflare interface, I can do this into "myzone-something" > "SSL/TLS" > "Overview" > "Full strict".

Although I can create a single page rule with Terraform to enable that SSL mode (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/page_rule), I would like to know if there is any way to set it directly at the zone level with Terraform ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [cloudflare_zone_settings_override (Resource)](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/zone_settings_override) and set "ssl" parameter to "strict".
Available values for that parameter is: "off", "flexible", "full", "strict", "origin_pull".